# Google play game services Leaderboard with custom UI using Unity3d plugin of google

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games, leaderboard

We want to display all leaderboard data into our custom created UI for the game. for that we want to access top scores info such as Profile Picture,Score and Name of the player.

All data will be shown in our custom created UI

we are using following unity3d plugin of google
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

Please let us know how to access all players data of our game leaderboard

Answer (score 0):

The you link provided has the actual documentation on how to use the plugin. From [Accessing Leaderboard data](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#accessing-leaderboard-data) (where you could get the Score) to [Getting Player names](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity#getting-player-names), where it is mentioned that you could

> use `Social.LoadUsers()` to load the player profile

from there you could get an [IUserProfile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SocialPlatforms.IUserProfile.html) to get the `image` and `username.` Sample from the same link:

```
internal void LoadUsersAndDisplay(ILeaderboard lb)
    {
        // get the user ids
        List<string> userIds = new List<string>();

        foreach(IScore score in lb.scores) {
            userIds.Add(score.userID);
        }
        // load the profiles and display (or in this case, log)
        Social.LoadUsers(userIds.ToArray(), (users) =>
            {
                string status = "Leaderboard loading: " + lb.title + " count = " +
                    lb.scores.Length;
                foreach(IScore score in lb.scores) {
                    IUserProfile user = FindUser(users, score.userID);
                    status += "\n" + score.formattedValue + " by " +
                        (string)(
                            (user != null) ? user.userName : "**unk_" + score.userID + "**");
                }
                Debug.log(status);
            });
    }
```

With all that said, if you were hoping for a *more detailed and precise sample*, it'd be considered as *too broad* here in Stack Overflow and may be voted to be closed.

Comment: Hello Mr AL. Thanks you very much for your answer we finally got success for adding custom leaderboard in our game Up: Adventure time https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aaryavarta.up      but it is showing limited number of users from global leaderboard. we have now more than 5000 users but when try to fetch data for 20 users its showing only 4-5 users.

Comment: Hi @AaryavartaTechnologies. Sorry, I haven't checked out Play Games for some time and can't recall much. But what comes to my mind is that it's possible that only that many players have the corresponding data (scores) to be displayed in the Leaderboards, then again, I could be wrong. Cheers!